# How can I optimize Mac OS X network log in time?

Tags: macos, performance, performance-tuning, network-profiles

I'm running an Open Directory server (Mac OS 10.6.7 Server) and a bunch of Mac clients (Mac OS 10.6.7).  On the clients, logging in to a local account is fast (less than 10 seconds between pressing Return at the Login Window and Finder being ready to use).

However, when logging into a network account (one authenticated by the Open Directory server, and whose home folder is an AFP share), logins take considerably more time --- between 1.5 and 3 minutes.  For the first 20-30 seconds after pressing Return at the Login Window, the progress meter spins without any other feedback.  Then it shows the username and icon for at least another minute, then, finally, Finder.

How can I troubleshoot this to figure out why it's taking so long?  Is there a log of what's happening during this time --- or, better yet, a way to generate a waterfall diagram (like BootVis in Windows XP, or Firebug)?

Comment: Looks like a question for Server Fault

Comment: @PleaseStand:  Maybe?  I don't know.  It seems to me questions like this occupy a grey area partway between Server Fault and Super User.  I created a Stack Exchange proposal for "Computer Lab Administration", but it didn't gain much traction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this in my clients' system logs:

```
5/14/11 11:00:51 PM SecurityAgent[2735] User info context values set for testuser
5/14/11 11:01:12 PM authorizationhost[2734] k5_authenticate(): got -1765328228 (Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm) on /SourceCache/SecurityAgent/SecurityAgent-39574/plugins/krb5/krb5_operations.c:84
5/14/11 11:01:12 PM authorizationhost[2734] -[SFBuiltinAuthenticate performDSPasswordAuth](): got -1765328228 (Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm) on /SourceCache/SecurityAgent/SecurityAgent-39574/authhostbuiltins.m:1039
5/14/11 11:01:13 PM SecurityAgent[2735] Login Window Showing Progress
```

KDC is running on the server, but the firewall ports were blocked.  I unblocked the KDC ports (TCP/UDP 88) by going into Server Admin > Firewall > Settings > Services > Allow: `Kerberos V5 KDC`, and now network login takes only 5-10 seconds, same as local accounts.